# sharepoint online How to handle onClickListeners, eventListeners?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I'm a newbie to Sharepoint online. I have done Migration project from Sharepoint 2007 to Sharepoint online (O365). Now comes the enhancements to the new site in sharepoint online. I'm searching without proper flow.

I hereby post the requirements as follows. Please guide me in this regard:

1. I have forms based on content type
2. I have a list named "sample_1", where there are many rows with "XXXX_details". If i click "multiple lines of text" field, it shows that rows data in the form view.

Till this ok. Now i need to create a button on the same page where when i click button, onClickListener, i need to create a task which should populate some of the fields in a row to the (1) form which i said in the First point.

Do this need **sharepoint Designer** or **Visual Studio**

If you unable to get what the question is, please comment and i clarify it.

1. Please clear the air "what are the requirements and steps" to create sharepoint online apps.

Any related answers or comments are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I undestand correctly. You have a SharePoint list form and on that form you want a button that creates a task in another list? If so, this is what I would do using javascript.

1. Add the button and javascript to the form through a content editor webpart. Either directly or through a linked html file.
2. In the onclick event of that button make either a rest call or a csom/jsom call to create the task list item.

Using something like jQuery or SPServices will probably help out on creating the list item.

Comment: Is the sharepoint designer is enough or do i need visual studio?

Comment: A text editor is enough, so SharePoint designer would do fine.

Comment: No, the scenario is I already having a List with data and Views. The thing is, i need to take some values in row with row ID or what so ever. I need to create another Task (i.e) new Row. For that i need to create a button in the each row view and by clicking that it should take me to the respective content type (form). There by the populated fields should not be able to edit. Rest of the content Type (form) fields should be able to enter values and create a new Task. R u getting me now?

Comment: Have a look at jsLink (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). This would give you the ability to add a button on each row in a view. if that button is there, it shouldn't be to hard to get the values of the row en build your own logic.

Comment: Can this be achieved using sharepoint designer?

Comment: As said before, a text editor will do, so SharePoint designer will do as well.Everything you do with javascript, you can do with SharePoint designer. I'm guessing you are quite new to this. To make this happen you probably need to gain some experience with javascript.

Comment: Ya, I'm new to sharepoint. But i know javascript. i have worked on it earlier. Let me try on it. Thanks a lot for ur suggestion.

Comment: If you are going to take a look at CSR/JSlink then check out the [Chrome Browser Cisar Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo?hl=en)

Comment: @MartijnE I tried using Javascript. But as far as now i get only the default **ID** value when i select the row in the list. But when i replace the another column name ex: **(XXXX)** with **ID** Column. The value shows as **undefined**. Can you comment any link to get the basics on this? It would be great if i get any lead to get this.

Comment: Does this help: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/using-jslink-to-implement-delete-buttons-for-list-view?

Comment: I used CamlQuery Builder to create the query. But i have to take the query to Javascript. In a mean while, I tried to create a Custom Ribbon in Action Tab in sharepoint designer. But i can't able to create drop down from that Ribbon. Can you suggest anything on this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish but this should be a separate question.